# Can't create a hard disk vdi

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am trying to create a Debian 32-bit machine in VirtualBox. I want to install it in a usb stick of 32GB size.

I have installed portable-box in the usb stick and when I create the Debian machine I choose create a virtual diks image of 25GB. I select fixed size and I choose 1024Mb of RAM. When the percentage of the machine created is approximately 20%, I watch the following error:

Could not create the medium storage unit 'F:\Debian\Debian.vdi'.
VDI: setting image size failed for 'F:\Debian\Debian.vdi' (VERR_DISK_FULL).

This means that the disk is full, but it's not true. I have 29GB of free space. 
I would like to know why I can't cerate the hard disk. I also try to create a 20GB and 15GB disks and I can't due to the same error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your USB stick **is not formatted as Fat32** and try to format it as NTFS.

Comment: And the reason that could be it is because fat32 has a maximum single file size of 4GB.  NTFS doesn't.